# Comparing predicates

Tags: alloy

A poster asked how to compare functions in Alloy. While testing a small example (comparing predicates instead of functions) to answer the question with, I've noticed the following behavior, which puzzles me.

The analyzer finds no counterexamples whenever the boundary of the check command is higher than 3 and the fact 'f1' is active. Inactivating the fact, the analyzer works as expected. Why does the redundant fact 'f1' modify the analyzer's operation so and why just in the case the boundary is higher than 3?

```
open util/ordering [V]
sig V {}

fact f1 {
    # V > 0
}

pred p1 [x: V] {
    x = last
}

pred p2 [x: V] {
    x = first
}

assert a1 {
    all x: V | p1[x] <=> p2[x]
}

check a1 for 3
```

It appears that whenever the check boundary is 4 or higher and 'f1' is active the analyzer reports '0 vars. 0 primary vars. 0 clauses.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable at the moment to look into the details, but it seems likely that you're seeing overflow behavior, based in part on the fact that Alloy's integers are very narrow (4 bits by default, I believe?) twos-complement integers, so overflow happens regularly.

Several changes might be instructive, separately or together, to see if they affect the behavior.

- replace fact f1 with `some V`
- turn on the "Forbid Overflow" option
- provide an explicit bit width for Int using the `scope` command (for other signatures, the scope number specifies a maximum number of instances; for Int it specifies a bit width)

As Loïc Gammaitoni has put it in another question here "You should always be careful when playing with numbers in Alloy".

Comment: Specifying a higher Int scope has resolved the issue. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I would add that once you set an ordering on a signature, the number of atoms typed by that signature is bound to be the scope for which the analysis is run. you can thus get rid of fact1.